# Why am i getting the wrong inertia moment tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Let the x axis be parallel to one side of the rectangle, so as the z xis. Let the y axis be parallel to the normal.

The x side of the rectangle is a and is 2a for the z axis.

I should calculate $Ixx, Iyy, Izz$. In fact, i was able to calculate it, and i  got:
$$Ixx,Iyy,Izz = 4Ma^2/12,Ma^2/12,5Ma^2/12$$

The strange thing is that the answer is
$$Ixx,Iyy,Izz = Ma^2/12,5Ma^2/12,4Ma^2/12$$

That is, it is changed. Now, you could guess that maybe i have confused the axis, but no, there is this image which shows the correct configuration:

[image]

I would like to know if you got the same answer as me, or if your answer is equal to the book, because if it is equal to the book, it means that i have interpreted the moment of inertia's formula wrong.

Comment: great, and I get $(I_{xx},I_{yy},I_{zz})=\left(\frac{4Ma^2}{12}, \frac{5Ma^2}{12}, \frac{Ma^2}{12}\right)$. Integrating over the rectangle, $R$, we have $\int_Rx^2\,dm=\frac{Ma^2}{12}, \int_Ry^2\,dm=0, \int_Rz^2\,dm=\frac{M(2a)^2}{12}$. So, adding them up appropriately, we find the above result.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I concur.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you show your calculation steps it is not possible to see where you went wrong. But here *a* correct way of solving this problem.

#### MMOI Transformation

In the body coordinates $(x,y,z)$ the [mass moment of inertia of a solid cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#:%7E:text=2%7D%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%7D%7D-,Solid%20cuboid,-of%20width%20w) in tensor form is

$$ I_{\rm xyz} = \begin{vmatrix} \tfrac{m}{12} (\Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2) & & \\ & \tfrac{m}{12} (\Delta x^2 + \Delta z^2) & \\ & & \tfrac{m}{12} (\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2) \end{vmatrix}$$

Given that $\Delta x = a$, $\Delta y = 0$ and $\Delta z = 2 a$

$$ I_{\rm xyz} = \begin{vmatrix} \tfrac{m}{3} a^2 & & \\ & \tfrac{5 m}{12} a^2 & \\ & & \tfrac{m}{12} a^2 \end{vmatrix}$$

The rotation is clockwise so the rotation matrix about the *y*-axis is

$$ \mathrm{R} = \begin{vmatrix} \cos \alpha & 0 & -\sin \alpha \\
 0 & 1& 0 \\
\sin \alpha & 0 & \cos \alpha \end{vmatrix} $$

Given the geometry $\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$ which is used to find the MMOI on the $(x',y',z')$ coordinate frame

$$ I_{\rm x'y'z'} = \mathrm{R}\, I_{xyz} \mathrm{R}^\top $$

Do the linear algebra and you find

$$ I_{\rm x'y'z'} = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{17 m}{60} a^2 & & \frac{m}{10} a^2 \\
 & \frac{5 m}{12} a^2 & \\ \frac{m}{10} a^2 & & \frac{2 m}{15} a^2 \end{vmatrix} $$

Which matches none of the results. Someone care to poke holes?

---

#### Verification

Consider the following CAD model, with mass $m=12$ and $a=1$ such that the body MMOI end up being $I_{\rm xx} = 4 (\tfrac{m}{12} a^2)$, $I_{\rm yy} = 5 (\tfrac{m}{12} a^2)$ and $I_{\rm xx} = 1 (\tfrac{m}{12} a^2)$ as described above.

[image: fig1]

Now rotate the object in order to align the *x'* axis to one corner and measure $I_{rm x'x'}$, and $I_{rm z'z'}$ which are different

[image: fig2]

$I_{\rm x'x'} = \tfrac{17}{5} (\tfrac{m}{12} a^2)$

[image: fig3]

$I_{\rm z'z'} = \frac{8}{5} (\tfrac{m}{12} a^2)$

Both values match the calculations above, since $\tfrac{m}{12} a^2=1$ in the CAD model.

Comment: I don't see how you added things up for $I_{xyz}$. For example, 
 - $I_{xx}=\int_R(y^2+z^2)\,dz=\int_Ry^2\,dm+\int_Rz^2\,dm=0+\frac{M(2a)^2}{12}=\frac{4Ma^2}{12}$.

 - $I_{yy}=\int_R(x^2+z^2)\,dm=\int_Rx^2\,dm+\int_Rz^2\,dm=\frac{M(a^2)}{12}+\frac{M(2a)^2}{12}=\frac{5Ma^2}{12}$.

 - $I_{zz}=\int_R(x^2+y^2)\,dm=\int_Rx^2\,dm+\int_Ry^2\,dm=\frac{M(a)^2}{12}+0=\frac{Ma^2}{12}$.

In any case, you should be having some $+0$ terms, because the body lies on the plane $y=0$, so $\int y^2\,dm=0$, but you do not have that, so your first matrix can't be right.

Comment: @peek-a-boo - the [standard formula for a rectange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#Moments_of_inertia) of sides $(a,b)$ is $I = \frac{m}{12} ( a^2+b^2)$. I assumed the object has two sides of size $a$ and the third of size $2a$.

Comment: ok, now I see where you got your numbers from, but based on the picture, it seems to be a thin rectangular sheet, i.e a set of the form $\{(x,y,z)\,:\, -\frac{a}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{a}{2}, y=0, -a\leq z\leq a\}$ (also OP says as much, calling the object a rectangle rather than a cuboid of something else to suggest it's a 3D solid object; also based on OP's supposed answer key, it seems the 2D thin rectangular sheet interpretation is the right one).

Comment: @peek-a-boo - I have updated the answer to reflect the 0 dimension on the _y_ axis.

Comment: @peek-a-boo - I added validation using CAD. I now stand by my expressions as the correct ones.